# Pods framework bidirectional rels mess

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

I've got quite some problems with pods framework and the bidirectional relationship system.
 I have 4 pods, Resources, Sources, Feeds, Topics.

These are the relationships:

- Resources <-----> Topics (multi), Feeds (multi), Sources (mono)
- Sources <-----> Topics (multi), Resources (multi)
- Feeds <-------> Topics (multi), Resources (multi)
- Topics <------> Resources (multi), Sources (multi), Feeds (multi).

I have an Ajax based process which for every topic, for every feed connected to the topic, collects the urls in the feed rss plus some more data. For every url that was found the system checks if its domain (the source) is already in the Sources database. If not, saves the Source and the Resource. If yes instead checke if the resource is already in the Resources database, and if yes makes two add_to() to that resource, for the actual topic and feed in the loop thus adding them to the Resource if not already saved.
Linear isn't it?

But in reality it's a mess!!! for some reason this process is also altering the connections between feeds and topic adding the seconds to the first in case of duplicates. There is one catch all topic with many duplicates with the other topics and this is up with all the feeds after running the process. The relationships fo feeds and topics should not cjange during the process!! I suspect it's the Resources objects that drove the modification.

Please I really need help  to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something for StackOverflow, this is something we are currently working through via bug you previously reported on our official bug tracker at:

https://github.com/pods-framework/pods/issues/1506